# ScrollView in headerView of UITableView can't respond to scroll down event at first

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

As title said, scrollView in headerView couldn't respond to scroll down event at first. It scrolls down the tableView.

And After zoom the scrollView in headerView it becomes alright.

I wish there is a way to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It was caused by setting the wrong contentSize to the scrollView.